# better way to condition preference sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table named `items` as follows:

```
id oId key    value
1  0   color  green
2  0   size   30
3  1   color  red 
4  2   color  blue
```

Above rows with `oId=0` specifies the default values of items .
I need to select all `key`, `value` of an item with a particular `oId` which will include the default (oId=0), if a specific `key` and `value` for that `oId` does not exists.

For eg. For item 2 , it should return

```
id oId key   value
1  0   size  30
2  2   color blue
```

I have written the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM items AS i
WHERE i.oId=0 AND
i.key NOT IN (SELECT key FROM items WHERE oId=2) 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM items WHERE oId=2
```

Is there a way to optimize the above query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JOIN on the right index:

```
SELECT t1.`key`, IFNULL(t2.value, t1.value)
FROM `items` AS t1

LEFT JOIN `items` AS t2
ON t1.`key` = t2.`key` AND t2.`oId` = 2

WHERE t1.`oId` = 0;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5873e/2)